# I can't understand how to prove this inequality

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

I don't understand how we can prove that inequality, without integration
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x} \left(2-\frac{1}{y+2}\right)\,dy \geq 2 - \frac{1}{x+2}.$$

P.S: Here is what I try... if can someone help me to continue I appreciate very much $$\int _x^{2x}\:\left(2-\frac{1}{y+2}\right)\,dy=F(2x)-F(x)$$ There is $c\in\left(x,2x\right)$ so $F'(c)=\frac{F(2x)-F(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x} \int_x^{2x}\left(2-\frac{1}{y+2}\right)\,dy$ but $F'(c)=f(c)=2-\frac{1}{c+2}$ and after how can I continue to prove inequality?

Comment: Have you computed the value of the integral?  That part shouldn't be hard...

Comment: Why don't you want to compute an easy integral?

Comment: Perhaps think about what happens if x gets very large

Comment: If you want to avoid integration, think Mean Value Theorem if you want to be formal, or areas if informal is good enough.

Comment: Here is what I try... if can someone help me to continue I appreciate very much $$\int _x^{2x}\:\left(2-\frac{1}{y+2}\right)dy=F\left(2x\right)-F\left(x\right)$$ There is $c\in\left(x,2x\right)$ so $F^,\left(c\right)=\frac{F\left(2x\right)-F\left(x\right)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\int _x^{2x}\left(2-\frac{1}{y+2}\right)dy$ but
$F^,\left(c\right)=f\left(c\right)=2-\frac{1}{c+2}$ and after how can I continue to prove inequality?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I missed somewhere?

Comment: The MVT for integrals tells us that $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=(b-a)f(c)$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$. Note that in our case $f(c)\ge f(a)$. (I am assuming $x$ is positive. We can also look at negative $x$, though certainly there is a problem if our interval includes $-2$.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't understand why Aurizio tell me $\int _a^b\:\frac{dx}{x+2}\ge \frac{b-a}{b+2}$, how help me that? can you explain?

Comment: I cannot find the comment you refer to.  The relevant fact (with $x=a\gt 0$) is that $\int_a^b \frac{dt}{t+2}\le \frac{b-a}{a+2}$.

Comment: is the last on "Where am I wrong in the following limit?"

Comment: @AndréNicolas and how to help us this relevant fact?

Comment: That is the fact used in the answer by Matthias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}2dy = 2$$ one only needs to show that
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{y+2}\,dy \leq \frac{1}{x+2}$$
For positive $x$ let us define $f(x):=\frac{1}{x+2}$ which is strong monotone falling.
Thus you can say 
$$\forall y\ge x: f(y)\le f(x)$$
Thus the integral is given by the boundary

$$\int_x^{2x}f(y)dy\le \int_x^{2x}f(x)dy= x f(x)$$ which is equivalent to the second equation here
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}f(y)dy\le f(x)$$

Comment: Nice answer, but you should account for the possibility that $-1 < x < 0$ or $x < -2$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. you are right. Sorry, I run out of time now. Maybe I fix it later or you might.

Comment: @Matthias $\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}f(y)dy\le f(x)$ is wrong, we need to prove that $\frac{1}{x}\int _x^{2x}f\left(y\right)dy\ge \:f\left(x\right)$

Comment: @Lucas Note the minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)=2-\frac1{t+2}$ and $F(t)=\int f(x)dx$

Note that $f$ is an increasing function on $R-${$0$}

Now that inequality can be written by $\frac{F(2x)-F(x)}x \ge f(x)$

By mean value theorem , there is $c$ s.t.

$x<c<2x$ and $\frac{F(2x)-F(x)}x=F'(c)=f(c)$

But $f$ is increasing so $f(c)>f(x)$

It follows that inequality

Comment: user128766 can you help me in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242065/how-to-evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-frac1x5-cdot-int-0x-f-leftt-righ  with mean value theorem