# How to evaluate $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^5}\cdot \int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt$ with MVT

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

We have to evaluate $\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{1}{x^5}\cdot \int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt$

where $f\left(x\right)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\log\left(1+x\right)$ , $\:x\in \left(-1,\infty \right)$

I don't want to solve with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

With MVT I obtain: $\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{f(x)}{x^4}=\frac{1}{4}$, but the correct answer is $\frac{1}{20}$ and I think here we can't use MVT, and if I've right, can somebody explain why?

Here is all steps: $c\in (0,x)\text{ so }\int _0^x\:f(t) \, dt=x\cdot f(c)$.
So 
$\lim _{x\to 0 }\left(\frac{f(c)}{x^4}\right)=\lim _{x\to 0 } \frac{f(x)}{x^4}=\frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the FToC?

Comment: I want to see what is wrong with MVT, because with FTOC I obtain what I want, my purpose is not just to solve ... not motivate me ...

Comment: @GFauxPas can you help me?

Comment: Clearly $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) / x^4 \neq 1/4$, it's zero.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer should be zero, since $$\int_{0}^xf(t)\:dt=x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{12}-\log(1+x)-x \log (1+x)$$ Now the result when dividing by $x^5$ should be $\mathcal{O}(x^{-1})$.

Comment: @LeonAragones and Uncountable, verify with FTOC and you will see the correct answer is not zero, is $\frac{1}{20}$ but it does not interest me, but to find why with MVT doesn't work...

Comment: @Lucas I don't know how to do this without the FToC, so I cannot help you.

Comment: Okay, but did you verify with FTOC? if yes, how did you get?

Comment: As everybody here tells you, the answer is $0$, not $\frac 1 4$, neither $\frac 1 {20}$. As you can see when computing the limit of $\frac {f(x)} {x^4}$, the dominant term is $\frac {x^3} {3x^4}$, which goes to $0$.

Comment: The answer is not $frac{1}{20}$, it is zero.  And I admonish you not to refer to someone as "dude."  It is offensive.

Comment: @Lucas Please show us how you derive that the answer should be $\frac{1}{20} $, using FTOC (or any other way), because I'm thinking you might be confusing with $\lim_{x \to 0}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm sorry for this callousness to say you "dude" and Uncountable now I looked again and you've right, I will fix point

Comment: You have $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ in the title and $\lim_{x\to0}$ in the question. Which one is right?

Comment: I forgot to edit title... sorry I'll fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the general mean value theorem?

In brief, there is $c$ s.t.

$a<c<b$ and $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac {f'(c)}{g'(c)}$

So consider $F$ as primitive function of $f$ then your limit can be written by

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x^5-0}$

Apply G.M.V.T so $\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x^5-0} = \frac {f(c)}{5c^4}$ where $0<c<x$ or $x<c<0$

If $x\to0$ then also c is

Hence your limit is same to $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{5x^4}$

and final limit converges to 0(Try this. It's your assignment)

Comment: Where is $4c^3$? and above $5c^4$ is due to $g(x)=x^5$ Oh I'm sorry third line equation is omitted $f' , g'$

Comment: now I understand, but why this don't work on the first MVT ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm late. If you want to use the first MVT then set $h(x)=\frac {f(x)}{x^4}$. But you need these point , 1) $h(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ so h is continuous at $x=0$ and $h(0)=0$ 2) calculate $h'(x)$ as $x \to 0$. My answer is one step as 2), since 1) can be omitted.

Comment: if you calculate $h′\left(x\right)$ you don't obtain same value like GMVT, because in GMVT $\frac{f\left(x\right)}{5x^4}\ne h\left(x\right)$ ,  where is the problem?

Comment: Oh $h$ is not that. Not $f$, F is true. So limit's entry can be written by
$\frac {h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}$. And $h'(x)$ must have same value as $x \to 0$

Comment: I have a question: what did you led to write $h\left(x\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^4}$ ?

Comment: If you want to use MVT, a fraction has a form $\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$.
Particularly, if $y=f(y)=0$ then that fraction's form is $\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$=$\frac {f(x)}x$. So I just remained $x$ in denominator and collected others(and it's $h$) in numerator

Comment: but we can change $f\left(c\right)$ with $f\left(x\right)$?because I have $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(c\right)}{x^4}\right)$

Comment: Ummmm.... what's your mean?

Comment: from what I understand $f\left(x\right)\:with\:f\left(c\right)$, therfore $\frac{f\left(c\right)}{x^4}\ne \frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^{\text{4}}}$, or am I wrong?

Comment: OK. Of course there two fraction is not same so you can not change c and x. But in this case $\frac {f(x)}{x^4}$ converges to 0 as x $\to$ 0 so two fraction's limit have same value.

Answer (score 2):

If one is restricted from using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, then one can proceed to carry out the integration of $f$.  To that end

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^x f(t) dt &= \int_0^x \left((t-\frac12 t^2+\frac13 t^3-\log(1+t) \right)dt\\\\
&=\frac12x^2-\frac16x^3+\frac{1}{12}x^4-(x+1)\log(x+1)
\end{align}$$

Then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^x f(t)dt=0$$

Comment: This is using the FToC.

Comment: Why do you say that?  The limit of Riemann sums provides the result and that doesn't link the integral to the derivative, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The answer below is to an earlier version of the problem, where the limit as $x\to\infty$ was sought. For the revised question, where $x\to 0$, we can use the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$.

Your MVT argument will work. Since we are interested in the limit as $x\to\infty$, we can take $x$ to be positive. For $x$ large, we have 
$$0\lt f(c)\lt c+\frac{c^3}{3}\lt x+\frac{x^3}{3}.$$ It follows that
$$0\lt \frac{xf(c)}{x^5}\lt \frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{3x}.$$
Now Squeezing shows that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Please note that the OP changed from $x \to \infty$ to $x \to 0$, so the answer becomes irrelevant.

Comment: when $x->0\:$ this is equal with $\frac{1}{20}$, but I don't know how can I continue with MVT